# c: when using a pointer as input in a function incrementing the pointers value by using *pointer++ doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, operators, operator-precedence

While I was learning C (I am very new to it), I was playing around with pointers. Here you can see my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int *i)
{
    *i += 1;  
}

int main()
{   
    int num = 3;

    printf("%d\n", num);
    change(&num);
    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

My aim was to replace incrementing the num value without reassigning it like so:

```
num = change(num);
```

That's why I was passing the memory location of `num` using the `&`: so it could be used as a pointer. Before this version everything in the code was the same. The only thing that was different was that I said `*i++;` instead of saying `*i += 1;`

Now my question is why can't I say `*i++`?

Comment: Operator precedence: postfix increment has higher precedence than unary indirection, has higher precedence than compound assignment.

Comment: Being German is no excuse for bad English!

Comment: @Olaf Ich bin Deutscher and still have problems with the English.

Comment: @Michi: Das ist trozdem no reason to add such an excuse (too chatty). The English is good enough. Das ist eine typisch deutsche Eigenschaft.

Comment: @Olaf You right like Always :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now my question is why i can't say *i++

Due to operator precedence, `*i++` is same as `*(i++)`.

```
*(i++);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int* temp = i;  // Store the old pointer in a temporary variable.
i++;            // Increment the pointer
*temp;          // Dereference the old pointer value, effectively a noop.
```

That is not what you want. You need to use `(*i)++` or `++(*i)`. These will dereference the pointer first and then increment the value of the object the pointer points to.

Comment: `*(i++), which is  not what you want` It will be good for the OP to know why.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

You can see that "postfix increment" is at precedence level 1, and "Indirection (dereference)" at level 2, and level 1 happens first. So you need to use brackets to get the dereference to happen first: `(*i)++`.

The difference is `(*i)++` says locate the memory pointed to by `i`, and increment it (which you want). `*(i++)` says increment `i` itself (so it points to the *next* memory address), and dereference that; which is possibly a no-op, and not what you want.

Comment: `So you need to use brackets to get the dereference to happen first: (*i)++` You could explain to the OP whats happen if he/she not do it.