# Why is ++ operator not preceding = operator

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, operator-precedence

Why in this example

```
*p++ = c;
```

is *p first equal to c then p is increased by one. I looked in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) table of operator precedence and it says that "=" operator is in 15. place and ++ (postfix) is first. It doesn't make sense to me. Example where i tried this:

```
      char in_line[LINELNG];
      char *cp;
      int c;

      cp = &in_line[0];
      while((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF){
              if(cp == &in_line[LINELNG-1] || c == '\n'){
                      /*
                       * Insert end-of-line marker
                       */
                      *cp = 0;
                      if(strcmp(in_line, "stop") == 0 )
                              exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                      else
                              printf("line was %d characters long\n",
                                      (int)(cp-in_line));
                      cp = in_line;
              }
              else
                      *++cp = c;
      }
```

Comment: Have you thought about just doing one thing at a time - makes the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: They are different operands. You are right about the precedence, but the assignment is happening on the value `p` points to while the increment is on the pointer.

Comment: because it's `p++`. increment P **AFTER** reading its value. `++p` would be "increment p, THEN read its value"

Comment: @EdHeal i would do it that way but i saw this example in a book so I wondered why it works like this.

Comment: It's odd that you ask about `*p++ = c` and yet your code contains `*++cp = c`. You do realize that those are different, right?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I appears to me that the problem is with the assignment.

Comment: @user3386109 yes i do realize, i just made it like that as an example.

Comment: @iharob Oh.. right. Stack overflow in my head..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511061/c-when-using-a-pointer-as-input-in-a-function-incrementing-the-pointers-value-b/38512455 . The downvoting is probably because this comes up so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre- and postfix forms of `++` and `--` have both a *result* and a *side effect*.  For `++x`, the *result* of the expression is `x+1`, and the *side effect* is that `x` gets incremented by 1.  For `x++`, the *result* of the expression is the current value of `x`, and the *side effect* is that `x` gets incremented by 1.

The expression

```
*p++ = c
```

is *parsed* as

```
(*(p++)) = (c)
```

and *evaluated* as though written as<sup>1</sup>

```
t = p
*t = c
p = p + 1
```

with the caveats that `*t = c` and `p = p + 1` can happen in any order with respect to each other, and that `p` is only evaluated once.

Similarly,

```
*++p = c
```

is parsed as

```
(*(++p)) = c
```

and evaluated as though written as

```
t = p + 1
*t = c 
p = p + 1
```

with the same caveats as above.

---

1. This is a *logical* description of the evaluation, not necessarily code that the compiler generates.  The compiler may arrange things so that it doesn't use a temporary to store the current value of `p`.

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo-code expansions:

```
*p++ = c;
```

is the equivalent of

```
*p = c;
p = p + 1;
```

while

```
*++p = c;
```

is the equivalent of

```
p = p + 1;
*p = c;
```

`++` does bind tighter than most any other operator in C, but its pre-/post-fix location determines exactly what happens to the value in in `p` and when it's used.

Comment: Thank you. But i'm not sure why people are downvoting my question.

Comment: note the right column in the table you linked to. `right-to-left` precedence. so `*++p` and `++*p` are completely different. `*++p` increments p, then dereferences it, while `++*p` increments whatever p is pointing at, not whatever value p has.

Comment: @Warix3, I can't speak for other people, but I have noticed a trend on Stack Overflow that "simple" questions get downvoted.  We tend to forget what it's like to be a beginner, so we consider the basics too trivial to respond to and try shaming newbies for asking about them.  Even Marc B didn't upvote you're answer (I don't know if he downvoted).  My point is: don't get too discouraged from down votes here.  You asked a good question and I hope you follow it up by doing some reading on the C language about the order of operations.